# Trying to create toggle for icon in NavBar using a checkbox

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am trying to use a checkbox to make my font awesome icon trigger the menu icon to open and close the menu (which is how I want it to be design wise) when the screen is in mobile view.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```css
/*** General ***/

* {
  font-family: 'Noto Serif SC', serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bluepic {
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}

.contents1 {
  margin-top: 5vh;
  margin-bottom: 10vh;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin: none;
  padding: none;
}


/*** Header ***/

.header {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.logo {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}


/*** Navigation ***/

.fa-bars {
  display: none;
}

.nav-links {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: sticky;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(228, 224, 224);
  display: flex;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  float: left;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}

.nav-links li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}


/*** Footer ***/

.footer {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer2 {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}


/*** Media Queries ***/

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .bluepic {
    padding-top: 10px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 375px;
    height: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .bluepic {
    padding-top: 10px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 350px;
    height: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .fa-bars {
    font-size: 20px;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .logo {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  .nav-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-links,
  ul {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(107, 76, 76);
    top: 80px;
    left: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-toggle:checked+.nav-links,
  ul {
    display: flex;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    display: block;
  }
  .contents1 {
    margin-top: 5vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Serif+SC:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">

<div class="header">
  <div>
    <div class="logo">
      <h4>The Blue Lion <i class="fas fa-bars" id="nav-toggle"></i></h4>
        <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle">
    </div>
  </div>

  <label for="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle-label">
    <span></span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="navbar">
  <div class="nav-links" id="myTopnav">
    <ul>
      <li a href="#">Food</li>
      <li a href="#">Drink</li>
      <li a href="#">Covid-19</li>
      <li a href="#">News</li>
      <li a href="#">Join the Team</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="contents1">
  <img src="https://mcdn.wallpapersafari.com/medium/84/3/pQuUz4.jpg" class="bluepic" alt="Blue">
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <div class="info">
    Leave us a review:
    <i class="fab fa-tripadvisor"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="socialiconsf">
    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer2">
  <p>
    © The Blue Lion 2021
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at your HTML structure. The checked state can only influence styling of things that are at the same level afterwards (siblings) or children. The list that you want to show on click is outside that. Also (though this is not the problem here) ids must be unique.

Comment: As you are a new contributor, please remember to mark an answer as **accepted answer** if you feel it solved your issue (or comment with further details if your issue has not been solved). That way, other contributors would see that your issue has been solved and can concentrate on other questions pending - thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Noto Serif SC', serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bluepic {
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}

.contents1 {
  margin-top: 5vh;
  margin-bottom: 10vh;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin: none;
  padding: none;
}


/*** Header ***/

.header {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.logo {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}


/*** Navigation ***/

.fa-bars {
  display: none;
}

.nav-links {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: sticky;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(228, 224, 224);
  display: flex;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  float: left;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}

.nav-links li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}


/*** Footer ***/

.footer {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer2 {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}


/*** Media Queries ***/

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .bluepic {
    padding-top: 10px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 375px;
    height: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .bluepic {
    padding-top: 10px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 350px;
    height: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .fa-bars {
    font-size: 20px;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .logo {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  .nav-toggle {
    display: none;
    
  }
  .nav-links,
  ul {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(107, 76, 76);
    top: 80px;
    left: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-toggle:checked+.nav-links,
  ul {
    display: flex;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    display: block;
  }
  .contents1 {
    margin-top: 5vh;
  }
}
@media (max-width:600px){
    .hamburger-menu{
    
    position: relative;
}
    .checkbox:checked~ .nav-links{
        display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div>
    <div class="logo">
      <h4>The Blue Lion 
        
      
            </div>
        
      </h4>
    </div>
    
    <label for="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle-label">
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

    <div class="navbar">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check" class="checkbox" hidden>
        <label for="check" class="fas fa-bars"></label>
        <div class="nav-links" id="myTopnav">
          <ul>
            <li a href="#">Food</li>
            <li a href="#">Drink</li>
            <li a href="#">Covid-19</li>
            <li a href="#">News</li>
            <li a href="#">Join the Team</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>


<div class="contents1">
  <img src="bluepic1.jpg" class="bluepic" alt="Blue">
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <div class="info">
    Leave us a review:
    <i class="fab fa-tripadvisor"></i>
  </div>
  
  <div class="socialiconsf">
    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer2">
  <p>
    © The Blue Lion 2021
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: What did you change? Where's the menu icon?

Comment: In mobile size you can see this.

Answer (score 0):

CSS modification:

The **font-awesome** library overrides your CSS. That is why your menu-icon (`.fa-bars`) wouldn't hide when not in mobile mode.

I made following corrections to your CSS:

1. **Changing** `.fa-bars` to `.fas.fa-bars`
2. **Adding** `!important` in mobile mode
   (to show always when media break-point (`... and (max-width: 600px)`)

```css
/*** Navigation ***/
.fas.fa-bars {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .fas.fa-bars {
    font-size: 20px;
    display: block !important;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

Click event handler on checkBox:

Also, if you want functionality to your checkbox, then you would have to add an event-handler in JS and add the `onClick=function()` in your HTML (and correct the issue of the multiple assigned id as mentioned in comments: I replaced `id="nav-toggle"` with `id="nav-toggle-bars"` for the `<i class="fas fa-bars"` element).

Following complete code for you to **Run code snippet** and comment if this is your desired outcome (please advise).

Expand to "**full-page**" and change your browser width to see effect
below media break-point (`... and (max-width: 600px)`)

```js
const menuToggle = document.getElementById("nav-toggle-bars");
let menuCheckBox;

function showHideNavToggle(event) {
  menuCheckBox = event.target;
  if (menuCheckBox.checked) {
    menuToggle.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    menuToggle.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/*** General ***/

* {
  font-family: 'Noto Serif SC', serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bluepic {
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}

.contents1 {
  margin-top: 5vh;
  margin-bottom: 10vh;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin: none;
  padding: none;
}


/*** Header ***/

.header {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.logo {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}


/*** Navigation ***/

.fas.fa-bars {
  display: none;
}

.nav-links {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: sticky;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(228, 224, 224);
  display: flex;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  float: left;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}

.nav-links li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}


/*** Footer ***/

.footer {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer2 {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}


/*** Media Queries ***/

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .bluepic {
    padding-top: 10px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 375px;
    height: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .bluepic {
    padding-top: 10px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 350px;
    height: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .fas.fa-bars {
    font-size: 20px;
    display: block !important;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .logo {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  .nav-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-links,
  ul {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(107, 76, 76);
    top: 80px;
    left: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-toggle:checked+.nav-links,
  ul {
    display: flex;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    display: block;
  }
  .contents1 {
    margin-top: 5vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Serif+SC:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">

<div class="header">
  <div>
    <div class="logo">
      <h4>The Blue Lion <i class="fas fa-bars" id="nav-toggle-bars"></i></h4>
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="showHideNavToggle(event)" id="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle">
    </div>
  </div>

  <label for="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle-label">
    <span></span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="navbar">
  <div class="nav-links" id="myTopnav">
    <ul>
      <li a href="#">Food</li>
      <li a href="#">Drink</li>
      <li a href="#">Covid-19</li>
      <li a href="#">News</li>
      <li a href="#">Join the Team</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="contents1">
  <img src="https://mcdn.wallpapersafari.com/medium/84/3/pQuUz4.jpg" class="bluepic" alt="Blue">
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <div class="info">
    Leave us a review:
    <i class="fab fa-tripadvisor"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="socialiconsf">
    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer2">
  <p>
    © The Blue Lion 2021
  </p>
</div>
```

**Note:**
I also corrected 2 html closing tags (one `</div>` eliminated and `</h4>` closing tag corrected and replaced img source with a link to a generic blue background)

Answer (score -1):

See this response in codepen.
https://codepen.io/threefingers/pen/PojZMpx

Add in your `::before` element icon, the code icons in your states.

```css
.mydiv{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

input + .mydiv::before{
  content: 'code icon 1';
}

input:checked + .mydiv::before{
  content: 'code icon 2';
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="Car"> I have a car 
<div class="mydiv"></div>
```

Comment: Please describe your solution on stackoverflow and include a code snippet.

Comment: @ArnoldDaniels like this? 
I'm new here in responses.